# Output different from input in unity-gain op-amp (voltage follower)

Tags: operational-amplifier, unity-gain

I am using an LM358p op-amp as a voltage follower (unity buffer).

I have a battery as a 9V voltage supply, two resistors for a voltage divider so that the non-inverting input of the op-amp gets 5.6 V. I checked this with a multimeter and it is correct.

The supply voltage to the op-amp (Vcc) is the same 9V from the same battery.

[image]

The output (Vout) is 2.9 V, whereas I would expect it to be 5.6 V (idealy) like the input.

**Why is the output not he same as the input?**

I then tried to replace the battery with a variable voltage supply. I can go to 13 V Vsupply, so that the non-inverting input goes to 8 V, **but** still see the output of the op-amp Vout is 2.9 V.

Am I doing something obviously wrong with my circuit?

Comment: @DKNguyen 200/(120+200) times the 9 V is 5.6 V, no?

Comment: Oh my bad, your resistors are backwards? 120/(120+320) = 3.3V which is kind of close.

Comment: No. Also, I checked, and the non-inverting input of the op-amp does get 5.6 V.

Comment: Hmmm............

Comment: Also, as I say in the question, the non-inverting input follows the Vsupply voltage up to 8 V and above. It's the output that is always at 2.9 V

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that.

Comment: Built on breadboad without having a capacitor between the GND and Vcc pins of the opamp? Or the capacitor is somewhere far away from the opamp, not within 2 cm wire length?

Comment: I have no capacitor.

Comment: Check the actual voltages on the pins- if you're using the first amplifier put the (-) probe **on pin 4** and measure  the voltages on pins 1,2,3, and 8.

Comment: -Vin=Vout otherwise wiring error or your schematic is wrong

Comment: LM358 is a dual  Op Amps package, try to connect the used Op Amp like shown here if you haven't done it: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa204a/sboa204a.pdf

Comment: Not all opamps operate well with a single supply rail configuration(only power and ground provided). could you check if providing a more negative voltage e.g -8V at -vcc of the opamp helps?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I get: 2.9, 2.9, 5.3, 8.7 for pins 1,2,3,8 with the - probe on pin 4.

Comment: @NoumanQaiser tried + and - 8 V as V+ and V-, same story.

Comment: Double check that there's nothing connected to the output other than a meter. A capacitor to ground (or V+) is **not** okay- especially with G=1. If there is nothing else, try another op-amp. You should generally have at least 100nF supply bypass but that's not likely what's causing this issue.

Comment: Ok I disconnected everything else from the output and now it works as expected. The output was plugged into a line of holes on a breadboard that was providing the Vcc for a hex inverter and a motor driver. Could it be that too much current was being drawn?

Comment: Yes most likely, certain OpAmps can deliver more current then others. Lm324 is a decent single supply opamp that can drive small loads, can u try it in simulation(proteus etc) and see if it performs any better.